# solr 7.5 suggester multi word search special character and number shows top

Tags: solr

I am using solr 7.5 suggeter. 
Actual result of suggest

```
acetic acid
acetic acid 1-[1-{4-[5-(4-{[(z)-1-acetoxy-ethoxycarbonylimino]-amino-methyl}-phenyl)-furan-2-yl]-phenyl}-1-amino-meth-(z)-ylidenecarbamoyloxy]-ethyl ester
acetic acid [1-[1-(4-fluoro-phenyl)-7-naphthalen-1-ylmethyl-4,5,6,7-tetrahydro-1h-indazol-3-yl]-meth-(e)-ylidene]-hydrazide
acetic acid (10r,13s)-17-(2-acetyl-2,3-dihydro-1h-imidazol-4-yl)
.
.
acetic acid amide
acetic acid oxime
```

Expected result

```
acetic acid
acetic acid amide
acetic acid basc
acetic acid casd
cetic acid 1-[1-{4-[5-(4-{[(z)-1-acetoxy-ethoxycarbonylimino]-amino-methyl}-phenyl)-furan-2-yl]-phenyl}-1-amino-meth-(z)-ylidenecarbamoyloxy]-ethyl ester
acetic acid [1-[1-(4-fluoro-phenyl)-7-naphthalen-1-ylmethyl-4,5,6,7-tetrahydro-1h-indazol-3-yl]-meth-(e)-ylidene]-hydrazide
acetic acid (10r,13s)-17-(2-acetyl-2,3-dihydro-1h-imidazol-4-yl)
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSuggest" positionIncrementGap="100">`enter code here`<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/> <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/></fieldType>
```

I am using AnalyzingLookupFactory lookupImpl. Is there any way to improve suggest.

Comment: Why is the expected result .. the expected result? The first one is sorted by regular rules, so to change that you'll have to define what the expectation is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: .. so what is the rules to achieve the sorting order as in the expected result? Sort anything with [a-z] first, then numbers and then special characters?